# How to save the scala function output to csv file?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using scala to run [this project](https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI) , Code looks like this:

```
package com.salesforce.hw

import com.salesforce.op._
import com.salesforce.op.evaluators.Evaluators
import com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureBuilder
import com.salesforce.op.features.types._
import com.salesforce.op.readers.DataReaders
import com.salesforce.op.stages.impl.classification.BinaryClassificationModelSelector
import com.salesforce.op.stages.impl.classification.BinaryClassificationModelsToTry._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
 * Define a case class corresponding to our data file (nullable columns must be Option types)
 *
 * @param id       passenger id
 * @param survived 1: survived, 0: did not survive
 * @param pClass   passenger class
 * @param name     passenger name
 * @param sex      passenger sex (male/female)
 * @param age      passenger age (one person has a non-integer age so this must be a double)
 * @param sibSp    number of siblings/spouses traveling with this passenger
 * @param parCh    number of parents/children traveling with this passenger
 * @param ticket   ticket id string
 * @param fare     ticket price
 * @param cabin    cabin id string
 * @param embarked location where passenger embarked
 */
case class Passenger
(
  id: Int,
  survived: Int,
  pClass: Option[Int],
  name: Option[String],
  sex: Option[String],
  age: Option[Double],
  sibSp: Option[Int],
  parCh: Option[Int],
  ticket: Option[String],
  fare: Option[Double],
  cabin: Option[String],
  embarked: Option[String]
)

/**
 * A simplified TransmogrifAI example classification app using the Titanic dataset
 */
object OpTitanicSimple {

  /**
   * Run this from the command line with
   * ./gradlew sparkSubmit -Dmain=com.salesforce.hw.OpTitanicSimple -Dargs=/full/path/to/csv/file
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.isEmpty) {
      println("You need to pass in the CSV file path as an argument")
      sys.exit(1)
    }
    val csvFilePath = args(0)
    println(s"Using user-supplied CSV file path: $csvFilePath")

    // Set up a SparkSession as normal
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName.stripSuffix("$"))
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // RAW FEATURE DEFINITIONS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Define features using the OP types based on the data
    val survived = FeatureBuilder.RealNN[Passenger].extract(_.survived.toRealNN).asResponse
    val pClass = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(_.pClass.map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor
    val name = FeatureBuilder.Text[Passenger].extract(_.name.toText).asPredictor
    val sex = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(_.sex.map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor
    val age = FeatureBuilder.Real[Passenger].extract(_.age.toReal).asPredictor
    val sibSp = FeatureBuilder.Integral[Passenger].extract(_.sibSp.toIntegral).asPredictor
    val parCh = FeatureBuilder.Integral[Passenger].extract(_.parCh.toIntegral).asPredictor
    val ticket = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(_.ticket.map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor
    val fare = FeatureBuilder.Real[Passenger].extract(_.fare.toReal).asPredictor
    val cabin = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(_.cabin.map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor
    val embarked = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(_.embarked.map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // TRANSFORMED FEATURES
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Do some basic feature engineering using knowledge of the underlying dataset
    val familySize = sibSp + parCh + 1
    val estimatedCostOfTickets = familySize * fare
    val pivotedSex = sex.pivot()
    val normedAge = age.fillMissingWithMean().zNormalize()
    val ageGroup = age.map[PickList](_.value.map(v => if (v > 18) "adult" else "child").toPickList)

    // Define a feature of type vector containing all the predictors you'd like to use
    val passengerFeatures = Seq(
      pClass, name, age, sibSp, parCh, ticket,
      cabin, embarked, familySize, estimatedCostOfTickets,
      pivotedSex, ageGroup
    ).transmogrify()

    // Optionally check the features with a sanity checker
    val sanityCheck = true
    val finalFeatures = if (sanityCheck) survived.sanityCheck(passengerFeatures) else passengerFeatures

    // Define the model we want to use (here a simple logistic regression) and get the resulting output
    val prediction =
      BinaryClassificationModelSelector.withTrainValidationSplit(
        modelTypesToUse = Seq(OpLogisticRegression)
      ).setInput(survived, finalFeatures).getOutput()

    val evaluator = Evaluators.BinaryClassification().setLabelCol(survived).setPredictionCol(prediction)

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // WORKFLOW
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    import spark.implicits._ // Needed for Encoders for the Passenger case class
    // Define a way to read data into our Passenger class from our CSV file
    val trainDataReader = DataReaders.Simple.csvCase[Passenger](
      path = Option(csvFilePath),
      key = _.id.toString
    )

    // Define a new workflow and attach our data reader
    val workflow =
      new OpWorkflow()
        .setResultFeatures(survived, prediction)
        .setReader(trainDataReader)

    // Fit the workflow to the data
    val fittedWorkflow = workflow.train()
    println(s"Summary: ${fittedWorkflow.summary()}")

    // Manifest the result features of the workflow
    println("Scoring the model")
    val (dataframe, metrics) = fittedWorkflow.scoreAndEvaluate(evaluator = evaluator)

    println("Transformed dataframe columns:")
    dataframe.columns.foreach(println)
    println("Metrics:")
    fittedWorkflow .save("/tmp/my-model1")
    println("model_saved")
    // Load the model
    val loadedModel = workflow.loadModel("/tmp/my-model1")
    println("model_loaded")
    // Score the loaded model
    val passengersDatas = DataReaders.Simple.csvCase[Passenger](
      Option(csvFilePaths),
      key = _.row_id.toString)
    val scores = loadedModel.setReader(passengersDatas).score()
    print("model_scored")
    scores.show(true)
    println(scores.collectAsList())
  }
}
```

So output is score and i want to save the output to csv file, If i am using score.show() it is showing 20 rows of result but using scores.collectAsList() is showing all the result data , How to save this data to csv format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show method by default displays the 20 records and collect api will get all results to driver.To write to csv use the below loc.

```
scores.write.csv(“filepath”)
```

If you get error then try in json format:

```
scores.write.json("file_path")
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> data type.

Comment: In your case as your data has complex objects it can not be saved to csv. That is expected.in that case please write it to a json file or parquet

Answer (score 0):

You can save (and load) any data produced by TransmogrifAI using Avro. In order to do you need to do as follows:

```
import com.salesforce.op.utils.spark.RichDataset._

scores.saveAvro(path) // save scores as avro
val loaded = loadAvro(path) // load scores saved as avro
```